# Parseint seems to not generate accurate outputs for small strings of numbers

Tags: typescript

I run the following code

```
function getLucky(s: string, k: number): number {

    function sumDigits(num: number): number {
        let answer: number = 0
        let quotient: number = 0
        let num_to_string = num.toString()
        
        let lenNum: number = num_to_string.length

        for (let i = 0; i < lenNum; i++){
            quotient = Math.floor(num / (10**(lenNum -1 -i)))
            answer += quotient
            num = num % (10** (lenNum -1 -i))
        }

        return answer 
    }

    let lenS: number = s.length
    console.log(lenS)
    let temp: string = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < lenS; i++){
        temp += (s[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96).toString()
    }
    console.log(temp)

    let answer: number = parseInt(temp)
    console.log(answer)

    for (let l = 0; l < k; l++){
        answer = sumDigits(answer)
    }

    return answer
};

console.log(getLucky("dbvmfhnttvr", 5))
```

and I got the following output

```
11
422213681420202218
422213681420202240
9
```

I do not why, but it seems that parseInt() does not work as expected. Could someone explain me why is this happening? Is there a better alternative option than parseInt() to circumvent this issue?

Disclaimer: I am aware that this is not the right way of using code, and that this algorithm is not efficient. However, this is not the point. It is important to point out this type of issues to show the drawbacks of some functions.

Comment: what should have been the output? why what is happening

Comment: The output should have been 422213681420202218; 422213681420202218;  5

Comment: For more details about the algorirhm: [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-digits-of-string-after-convert/)

Comment: BigInt values lose precision:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thanks @vaira, that solves the issue.

Comment: @vaira -- it would be great if you convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Nishant you can go ahead and do it, I saw you already wrote one.